# How to see the output after make in win7?

Tags: vim, windows-7

I am trying to developing under windows 7. After i install the newest version vim, i found that it won't print the output after make. I make cpp file with :make command. But it just redirect the output to a temp file under AppData. Did meet this condition before? I have tried to set makeprg to other command, but i always redirects the standard output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't very clear to me what you mean, but I suppose you are looking for

```
:copen
```

(open the `quickfix window`)

See

- [`:he quickfix`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html)

Comment: I use :ls instead of :cl by mistake. It's ok now.